# setting counters for Lemmas proposition etc

Tags: counters

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper]{amsart}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % not needed with up-to-date TeX systems
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} % do you *really* need it?
\usepackage{datetime}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{construction}{Construction}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\newtheorem*{question}{Question}
\newtheorem*{solution}{Solution}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise} 

\newcommand{\mc}{\mathcal}
\newcommand{\mf}{\mathfrak}
\newcommand{\xra}{\xrightarrow}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\textheight 9.3in 
\textwidth 6.5in
\calclayout

% metadata

%\date{\today}

\title{***}
\author{***} 

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

This is the minimal working example.

In this I am getting Definition 2.1, Lemma 2.1, Corollary 2.1

I am looking for a set counter that gives Definition 2.1, Lemma 2.2.

How do I change the code accordingly?

The following code

```
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{The}[equation]{Theorem}
\newtheorem{Dfn}[equation]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lem}[equation]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{Prs}[equation]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{Crl}[equation]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{Rmk}[equation]{Remark}
```

suggested by Mico is giving numbers which includes equations as well. I only want number sequence for theorem, lemma, proposition, corolalry etc but not equations.

Comment: For example, replace `\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]` by `\newtheorem{lemma}[definition]{Lemma}` so Lemma will use the same counter as Definition

Comment: The answer is contained in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/535798/5001) I posted on an earlier question of yours.

Comment: Potential duplicate: [Theorem/Definition/Lemma problem — Numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45817)

Comment: Remove `[equation]` from `\newtheorem{The}[equation]{Theorem}` and instead place `[section` at the end: `\newtheorem{The}{Theorem}[section]`.  Then replace `[equation]` by `[The]` for all the other theorem-class objects.  Read the user's guide for `amsthm` (`texdoc amsthdoc`); the numbering strategy is thoroughly explained there.

Comment: @barbara that was more or less what I had in my minimal working example.. It looks like I am missing something. can you post it as an answer with some details

Comment: This is really a duplicate, and I'll try to find a good link.  But I'll post an answer for general convenience.

Comment: thank you. @barbara

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical numbering structure of theorem-class objects in `amsthm` is the following:

`\newtheorem{<`*env name*`>}{<`*`text`*`>}[<`*`parent counter`*`>]` 
`\newtheorem{<`*env name*`>}[<`*shared counter*`>]{<`*text*`>}`

(This is very well explained in the user manual -- `texdoc amsthdoc`; this manual is included in TeX Live along with `amsthm`.)

The example in this question shows theorem-class objects numbered along with equations, but what is wanted is for them to be numbered with the same counter within sections.  Therefore, the definitions should be changed as follows:

```
\newtheorem{The}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{Dfn}[The]{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lem}[The]{Lemma}
```

etc.