# How do I make my Theorem, Corollary (and other) environments to share the same counter?

Tags: numbering, counters

I have a few self-defined theorem environments:

```
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prp}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theom}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[section]
```

And when I use two different types of them:

```
\begin{lemma}
A lemma.
\end{lemma}
\begin{coro}
A corollary.
\end{coro}
```

The output is like this:

> **Lemma 1.1.** A lemma.
>
> **Corollary 1.1.** A corollary.

If I am guessing correctly, they are using different copies of the section counter. How can I make them share the same section counter to generate an output like the following? Btw, the documentclass is article and no template is used.

> **Lemma 1.1.** A lemma.
>
> **Corollary 1.2.** A corollary.

---

**A minimal example:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{prp}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{theom}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[section]

\newcommand{\lem}[1]{\begin{lemma}#1\end{lemma}}
\newcommand{\thm}[1]{\begin{theom}#1\end{theom}}
\newcommand{\prop}[1]{\begin{prp}#1\end{prp}}
\newcommand{\cor}[1]{\begin{coro}#1\end{coro}}

\begin{document}
\begin{section}{First section}

\lem{A lemma.}
\cor{A corollary.}

\end{section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\newtheorem{coro}[lemma]{Corollary}`?

Comment: @Sigur Your suggestion doesn't work the way I want. Doing so gives **Corollary 1.1.1.** And if no lemma is present prior to the corollary, it becomes **Corollary 1.0.1.**

Comment: Which class are you using? `report` or `article`? Please, add a minimal code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @Sigur I've edited that into the question.

Comment: Your code produces Lemma 1.1 Corollary 1.1 and after my suggestion it works as you wished.

Comment: @Sigur Sorry, it does work. I ignored the difference between `\newtheorem{coro}[lemma]{Corollary}` and `\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}[lemma]`. But what is the difference exactly?

Comment: The 1st says that `coro` should use the same counter as `lemma` and the 2nd says that it should use its own counter, but preceded by the counter `lemma`.

Comment: @Sigur Thanks again. Very helpful. If you can combine your comments into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: If you are willing to use `amsthm`, the answer is given here: [setting counters for Lemmas proposition etc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/536002)